# The plugin doesn't activate in VueJS

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I tried to use [`vue-authenticate`](https://github.com/dgrubelic/vue-authenticate) in my app, but I've some problems using the plugins' methods. This plugin has as dependency [`vue-resource`](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource), so the first step is installing both packages.

The in `main.js` file, I import **and activate** both packages, including the specific configuration for local authentication:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import VueAuthenticate from 'vue-authenticate'
// ...
Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.use(VueAuthenticate, {
  baseUrl: 'http://sgc-server.dev',
  tokenType: 'Token'
})
```

Now, in my login component, named `Login`, create a method, called `aLogin` to avoid name conflicts:

```
// ...
methods: {
  aLogin: (_credenciales) => {
    this.$auth.login(_credenciales).then((_carga) => {
      // Ejecutamos la lógica que sigue a un login exitoso
      console.log(_carga)
    })
  }
} 
// ..
```

In this component, `credenciales` is an object, defined in `data()` with two properties, `username` and `password`. The method `aLogin` is called in a form on `submit` event.

```
<form class="form" @submit.prevent="aLogin(credenciales)">
```

But nothing happen, and have this in the console.

```
Login.vue?8031:64 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'login' of undefined
    at VueComponent.aLogin (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:1987), <anonymous>:18:18)
    at Proxy.boundFn (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:735), <anonymous>:125:14)
    at submit (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:7875), <anonymous>:21:13)
    at HTMLFormElement.invoker (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:735), <anonymous>:1657:18)
```

Why the `this.$auth` is `undefined` if it is already registered in `main.js`? How can activate it properly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do *not* define a method in Vue with a fat arrow function. If you do that, `this` does not refer to the Vue instance.

Try

```
methods: {
  aLogin: function(_credenciales){
    this.$auth.login(_credenciales).then((_carga) => {
      // Ejecutamos la lógica que sigue a un login exitoso
      console.log(_carga)
    })
  }
}
```

See [VueJS: why is “this” undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929650/vuejs-why-is-this-undefined)

Comment: No, it's not `window`. It's the component class (or constructor if you prefer).

Comment: @leo You're right in this case that it's not the window. It's the enclosing scope or undefined. But, it's not the class or constructor.