# VueJS: why is "this" undefined?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, this, vuejs2

I'm creating a component with [Vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/).

When I reference `this` in any of the the [lifecycle hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks) (`created`, `mounted`, `updated`, etc.) it evaluates to `undefined`:

```
mounted: () => {
  console.log(this); // logs "undefined"
},
```

---

The same thing is also happening inside my computed properties:

```
computed: {
  foo: () => { 
    return this.bar + 1; 
  } 
}
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bar' of undefined

Why is `this` evaluating to `undefined` in these cases?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use arrow function in vue computed does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971081/use-arrow-function-in-vue-computed-does-not-work)

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Both of those examples use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) `() => { }`, which binds `this` to a context different from the Vue instance.

As per the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Properties-and-Methods):

> Don’t use arrow functions on an instance property or callback (e.g. `vm.$watch('a', newVal => this.myMethod())`). As arrow functions are bound to the parent context, `this` will not be the Vue instance as you’d expect and `this.myMethod` will be undefined.

In order to get the correct reference to `this` as the Vue instance, use a regular function:

```
mounted: function () {
  console.log(this);
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use the [ECMAScript 5 shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) for a function:

```
mounted() {
  console.log(this);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It was so obvious and so useful at the same time. Felt like just an upvote wasn't enough!

Comment: Do you know why I had to use the inverse (switch from `function` to `arrow function`) to be able to use `this` inside the `then()` callback? 
https://github.com/Inndy/vue-clipboard2#sample-2

Comment: @NickeManarin the function you pass as the callback for `then` has its own `this`, so to instead have `this` reference the parent's context, you can use an arrow function. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Comment: It actually works , can someone note the differences between `function()` and `()=>` ?

Answer (score 18):

You are using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

The [Vue Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods) clearly states not to use arrow functions on a property or callback.

Unlike a regular function, an arrow function does not bind `this`. Instead, `this` is bound lexically (i.e. `this` keeps its meaning from its original context).

```
var instance = new  Vue({
    el:'#instance',
  data:{
    valueOfThis:null
  },
  created: ()=>{
    console.log(this)
  }
});
```

This logs the following object in the console:

`Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, frames: Window, …}`

Whereas... If we use a regular function (which we should on a Vue instance)

```
var instance = new  Vue({
    el:'#instance',
  data:{
    valueOfThis:null
  },
  created: function(){
    console.log(this)
  }
});
```

Logs the following object in the console:

`hn {_uid: 0, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: hn, _self: hn, …}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using the arrow function, you could pass the component instance (`this`) as parameter like :

```
computed: {
  foo: (vm) => { //vm refers to this 
    return vm.bar + 1; 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you cannot use the arrow funtion if you want to use the `this`. Because the arrow funtion doesn't bind `this`.

Comment: Already mentioned in [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51468056/4826457)