# $refs is undefined when window.addEventListener('focus') is being fired

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input ref='commandLine' />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted () {
    window.addEventListener('focus', this.pageFocused)
  },
  methods: {
    pageFocused: () => {
      console.log('pageFocused')
      console.log(this)
      this.$refs.commandLine.focus()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I want to set focus on `commandLine` input every time user get into my app. Unfortunately, when I try to use `$refs` in order to find my `<input>` object, it's null.

I suspect that it's because window.addEventListerer puts my function into different context, so `this` variable doesn't represent my component.

What is a clean way to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not define methods with arrow functions. In arrow functions `this` is bound lexically and will not point to the Vue.

```
methods: {
  pageFocused(){
    console.log('pageFocused')
    console.log(this)
    this.$refs.commandLine.focus()
  }
}
```

See [VueJS: why is “this” undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929650)

> I suspect that it's because window.addEventListerer puts my function
>   into different context, so this variable doesn't represent my
>   component.

Vue binds methods to the Vue object, so that particular code will work typically. You cannot however, bind an arrow function. Thus, your issue.

Comment: thanks, didn't know about it. I'll mark your answer as best when SO finally allow me to do so ;)

Comment: @Piotrek No problem :)