# ES6 arrow function 'this' puzzle in vue.js official github example

Tags: ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2, arrow-functions

Here is the my fork from github example fiddle of vue.js offcial site: [vue.js github example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jancat/vcupavzw/1/)

I `console.log(this)` in **fetchData** function expression, and it outputs vue component instance:
[image: this output]

But when I use arrow function with **fetchData** ([fiddle of arrow function this](https://jsfiddle.net/jancat/08mmn85v/1/)), it `console.log(this)` is `window`

I had learned arrow function concept, but I still confuse `this`. Why the second fiddle `this` bind to the global **window** object, and the first fiddle `this` bind to **vue component instance**?

What condition can't I use arrow function `this`?

Answer (score 2):

You should *never* use an arrow function to define a method with Vue, because with arrow functions, `this` is [defined *lexically*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

> An arrow function does not create its own this, the this value of the
>   enclosing execution context is used.

That means that, with Vue methods, `this` will point to the global object, or the window.

When a Vue is instantiated, Vue binds the methods defined in `methods` to the Vue object. An arrow function *cannot be bound*. It's `this` will always be the what it was originally.

That being the case, **you should always use a normal function to write a Vue method**.

This also applies to the data function, computed values, and lifecycle hooks. The only time you will generally use an arrow function is when you are defining a function *inside* one of your methods or computed values, as you might when defining a callback for an ajax call.

See [VueJS: why is “this” undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929650).

Note: there is *one* exception to never using an arrow function to define a Vue method and that would be if you never referenced `this` *at all* in the method. Those cases are exceedingly rare. You almost always end up needing to reference other parts of the Vue inside a method using `this`. That being the case, it should quickly become a habit to simply never define a Vue method with an arrow function.

Comment: So many fall into this trap thinking anything ES6 is better. The same is true in jQuery event handlers and in React's `createClass`, when using arrow functions, know the implications!

Comment: @AndrewLi Agreed. It's one of the most common mistakes I see.

Comment: @AndrewLi is this really the solution? My eslint goes beserk. In jQuery or React you would use bind function.

From MDN web docs:
The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.