# Unable to access `get` method in vue-resource

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-resource

I have a tiny `vue` app where I'm wanting to use `vue-resource` to request an api endpoint.

1. I've installed `vue-resource` via npm
2. I've added the `Vue.use(VueResource)` lines to my bootstrap file
3. I've setup my component like this to call the `.get` method

**Blog.vue**

```
...
mounted () {
  this.fetchPosts()
},
methods: {
  fetchPosts: () => {
    debugger;
    this.$http.get('my-url')
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
      })
  }
}
...
```

I've seen a few github issues and SO posts which touch on this type of problem but most seem to relate to incorrect configuration which I don't *think* I have (happy to be proven wrong!)

The specific console error I get is:

`Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"`

What's odd about this is that if you see my `debugger` line, if I `console.log` `this.$http.get` at that point I get:

```
function (url, options$$1) {
        return this(assign(options$$1 || {}, {url: url, method: method$$1}));
    }
```

If I let the code run and then attempt the `console.log` afterwards I get:

`Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

As a result I presume it's some kind of `this` context issue, but from what I can see the reference *should* be correct...shouldn't it?

Comment: Don't use arrow syntax on the methods, because you currently lost correct `this` context - use ES6 object shorthand `fetchPosts() { //...etc }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJS: why is "this" undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929650/vuejs-why-is-this-undefined)

Comment: @BertEvans Possibly now I know the answer, at the time however the debugger statement and presence of the `get` method confused me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods should not be arrows function. The `this` will not point to the vue instance if  a methods is declared using arrow function.

Use normal function instead:

```
methods: {
  fetchPosts(){
    debugger;
    this.$http.get('my-url')
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
      })
  }
```

You can see the warning [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods)

Comment: hero! thanks, that was it. Still 11 minutes to accept the answer though!

Comment: As a side point, why would the methods object not point to the vue instance? as someone new to view it's a bit awkward to want to use arrow functions where possible but needing to define older functions in other places. I foresee an issue where other developers may refactor out the `function` calls!

Comment: @dougajmcdonald i could not understand you completely.... when vue instance or a new component which is essentially an extension of vue instance is created Vue internally binds `this` using  `bind` to the vue instance. But `bind` cannot be used with arrow functions and `this` will be the context of its execution which is the module itself.