# how to get the component instance within an @click event?

Tags: vue.js, components, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a button in a Vue component

```
<el-button class='range-right' @click='deleteItem(item)'>delete</el-button>
```

within it's handler I want to invoke other methods of the component.
however, even though I can call `deleteItem` which is itself a component method, I cannot get at the actual component for other methods.

is there a way to pass something like a `$component` param to the `@click` event?

```
methods {
  deleteItem: (item, obj) => {
    let api = '/api/train/deleteItem?_id=' + item._id
    let resource = Vue.resource(api)
    let vm = this  // NOT a component
    window.delItem = this
    console.log('deleteItem.this', this)
    resource.delete(api)
    .then(items => {
      console.log('deleted')
      vm.methods.load() //<< fails
    })
  },
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJS: why is "this" undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929650/vuejs-why-is-this-undefined)

Comment: Never define a Vue method with an arrow function.

Comment: yep, the arrow func thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the arrow function as commented

See an example here using `function`:

https://jsfiddle.net/rvp6fvwp/

Arrow function is bound to the parent context as said here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Properties-and-Methods

> Don’t use arrow functions on an instance property or callback (e.g.
> `vm.$watch('a', newVal => this.myMethod()))`. As arrow functions are
> bound to the parent context, this will not be the Vue instance as
> you’d expect and this.myMethod will be undefined.

Comment: yes, that was it. a little vue gotcha! might be nice if the tooling gave some type of warning for that.