# Vue.js plugin error : undefined

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to use a plugin from [GodofBrowser](https://github.com/Godofbrowser/vuejs-dialog),  as stated but I am getting an error

```
  this.$dialog.confirm('Please confirm to continue')
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'confirm' of undefined
```

so this.$plugin is undefined .... why ?

```
// I installed it via npm 
npm install vuejs-dialog
```

**main.js**

```
// I imported it
import Vue from "vue"
import VuejsDialog from "vuejs-dialog"

// and I told Vue to install it 
Vue.use(VuejsDialog)
```

Then I am trying to use it in my App.vue, on 'click' method :

**App.vue**

```
    <template>
      <div id="app" class="container">
        <ul class="navigation">
          <li id="home"><router-link :to="{ name: 'Home' }" >Home</router-link></li>
          <li id="shoppinglists" v-if="!logged">
            <span @click.capture="clicked">
              <router-link :to="{ name: 'ShoppingLists' }" >Shopping Lists</router-link>
            </span>
          </li>
          <li v-else id="shoppinglists"><router-link :to="{ name: 'ShoppingLists', params: { id: currentUserId } }" >Shopping Lists</router-link></li>
        </ul>
        <router-view></router-view>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import store from '@/vuex/store'
    import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

    export default {
      name: 'app',
      methods: {
        clicked: (event) => {
          event.preventDefault()
          console.log('clicked!'). // got it in console
          this.$dialog.confirm('Please confirm to continue') // !ERROR
          .then(function () {
            console.log('Clicked on proceed')
          })
          .catch(function () {
            console.log('Clicked on cancel')
          })
        }
      },
      computed: {
        ...mapGetters({ currentUserId: 'getCurrentUserId', logged: 'getLogged' })
      },
      store
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: you have not imported VuejsDialog  in the last code demo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJS: why is "this" undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929650/vuejs-why-is-this-undefined)

Comment: Is it defined in the `package.json` as a dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common stumbling block with Vue applications -
you can find the following in the [official Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods):

> Don’t use arrow functions on an options property or callback, such as
> created: () => console.log(this.a) or vm.$watch('a', newValue =>
> this.myMethod()).
>
> Since arrow functions are bound to the parent
> context, this will not be the Vue instance as you’d expect, often
> resulting in errors such as Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
> of undefined or Uncaught TypeError: this.myMethod is not a function.

Try using a normal function instead:

```
methods: {
    clicked: function (event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      console.log('clicked!'). // got it in console
      this.$dialog.confirm('Please confirm to continue') // !ERROR
      .then(function () {
        console.log('Clicked on proceed')
      })
      .catch(function () {
        console.log('Clicked on cancel')
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: methods: {clicked: async function (event){event.preventDefault();}}

Answer (score 2):

Should use :  Vue.prototype , not this !

```
Vue.prototype.$dialog.confirm('Please confirm to continue')
```