# Vuex: _this.$store is undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuex

After adding Vuex to my project I am unable to access this.$store in any components. The error message is

> TypeError: _this.$store is undefined

I have looked at a bunch of questions already trying to solve this but as far as I can tell I'm doing everything right. Can anyone help? I am using the vue-cli webpack as my project base

main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import resource from 'vue-resource';
import router from './router';
import store from './store/index.js';

import App from './App';
import Home from './components/Home';
import NavButton from './components/atoms/NavButton';

Vue.use(resource);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  components: { App, Home, NavButton },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

/store/index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex);

const state = {
    isWriting: false,
    isLoggedIn: false,
}

const getters = {
    isWriting: state => {
        return state.isWriting;
    }
}

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state,
    getters,
});
```

App.vue

```
...
import NavBar from '@/components/organisms/NavBar';
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: { NavBar },
  created: () => {
    console.log(this.$store.state.isLoggedIn); // THIS LINE
  }
}
...
```

package.json

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-resource": "^1.3.6",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
...
```

Comment: Can't see `_this.$store` **anywhere** in your code. What **exactly** is the error message and what piece of code is producing it?

Comment: it is the console.log(this.$store.state.isLoggedIn). The error message exactly is `TypeError: _this.$store is undefined` @Phil

Comment: The error message does not match your code at all. Where is `_this` defined? Are you perhaps viewing an old / cached copy?

Comment: I have cache busted and never typed _this, that is just how the error message is showing up. If you add an underbar the error is `TypeError: _this is undefined`.

Comment: Might be your function definition. Try `created: function() { ... }` or just `created () { ... }`. The arrow function may be binding `this` to the the `App.vue` script context instead of the component. I imagine `_this` is coming from your transpiler

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJS: why is "this" undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929650/vuejs-why-is-this-undefined)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

SOLVED:

Using fat arrow on created is not correct, should be `created: function() {...}`

Comment: Hehe, I just suggested the very same thing. Glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 2):

When arrow functions are used "this" will not be the Vue instance as you’d expect since arrow functions are bound to the parent context. Instead,

```
    created() { //function body. "this" will be the Vue instance},
    mounted() {//function body. "this" will be the Vue instance},
    methods: { someFunc() {}, async someAsyncFunc {} }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem after moving the store from app.js to /store/index.js

I had to change `state.store.myValue` to `store.myValue` in the commits