# access vue data component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

i created a simple component but when i try to access data component it returns undefined
here is my code:

```
Vue.component({
  template:`<div>{{message}}</div>`,
  data() {
     return { comments: [
        {title: 'hello' , message: 'world'},
        {title: 'hellowww' , message: 'worldssss'},
     ]}
  },
  mounted: function() {
      console.log(this.comments) // undefined. dosnt work
      console.log(this.$root.comments) //undefined. dosnt work
      console.log(comments) //undefined. dosnt work
  }

});

var app = new Vue({
   el: '#root'
});
```

Comment: Is that missing `:` after comments unintentional or intentional?

Comment: Or the closing `</div>`.

Comment: yeah sorry i typed codes again , didnt copy so that happen ill edit it now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJS: why is "this" undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929650/vuejs-why-is-this-undefined)

Comment: i tried mounted () {  //codes  } , same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On of these may be due to the way you pasted in the question, but your code had some problems:

- The `Vue.component` didn't declare its tag name.

  - Notice I added `comments-component` in `Vue.component('comments-component', {`.
- The `template` of the component (`` template:`<div>{{message}}</div>` ``) declared a `message` variable that was not present.

  - I added `message: "check the console",` to `data()`.

At this point, the `mounted` and `this.comments` in

```
mounted: function() {
    console.log(this.comments)
}
```

Work as expected.

See **demo below**.

```js
Vue.component('comments-component', {
  template:`<div>{{message}}</div>`,
  data() {
     return { 
     message: "check the console",
     comments: [
        {title: 'hello' , message: 'world'},
        {title: 'hellowww' , message: 'worldssss'},
     ]}
  },
  mounted: function() {
      console.log(this.comments)
  }

});

var app = new Vue({
   el: '#root'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
<comments-component></comments-component>
</div>
```