# Vue Router - Passing Data from inside beforeEach

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm having a hard time passing Data (in this case userInfo-Token) from inside a `beforeEach(to, from, next)` Vue-Router middleware to the coressponding Vue-Component. I'm working on Vue-SinglePage components files as following:

**App.js** (entry Point)

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <Navigation/>
        <router-view/>
        <Footer/>
     </div>
</template>
```

**Router.js** (router-view)

```
routes: [
    {
        path: '/',
        meta: {requiresAuth: true}
    }
]

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

    if(to.meta.requiresAuth){
        // getting token form local storage
        const token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');

        // retrieving User Information
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer "+  token;
        axios.post('http://localhost:4000/auth').then((result) => {
            next();  // <-- how will the following component be able to work with the result?
        } 
    }
}
```

**Dashboard.js** ('./' Component)

```
export default {
    computed: {
        welcomMsg: () => 'Hello '   + result.userName
    }   
}
```

What i did so far:
I tried a passing the userInfo from Entry-Point -> Router -> Component as properties. However it didnt work due to the information being asynchronos.

I tried to attach the data inside the `beforeEach` to the meta-Object. But I find myself unable to access the meta-Object inside the Component.

Maybe my approach is totally wrong. In this case: Is there a better way to **pass the recieved UserData to Vue Components** and make them avaliable there?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would handle this by using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/), which is a state management library.

You'd need to use create a Vuex module and add it to your root Vue instance like so:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: { userData: {} },
  mutations: {
    SET_USER_DATA: (state, data) => state.userData = data,
  }
});

new Vue({     // your root Vue instance
  el: '#app', // or whatever you've bound to root instance to
  store,      // the reference to the Vuex store
  ...         // the rest of the root Vue definition
})
```

Now, the root Vue instance and all of its internal components will have a reference to the Vuex store via the `$store` property.

Then you can set the `userData` in you axios callback by calling `store.commit`, which will subsequently call the specified mutation in the Vuex Store (this would require that you also have the reference to the Vuex `store` object in this scope):

```
axios.post('http://localhost:4000/auth').then((result) => {
  store.commit('SET_USER_DATA', result);
  next();
});
```

And you can access the `userData` from any component via the `$store` object:

```
export default {
  computed: {
    welcomeMsg() {
      let { userName } = this.$store.state.userData || {};
      return (userName) ? 'Hello ' + userName : '';
    }
  }
}
```

*notice I also updated the `welcomeMsg` computed to fix the spelling and to [not use an arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929650/vuejs-why-is-this-undefined)*

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I didn't know you can do this. I will try it right now an give you feedback. Thanks!

Comment: @Aoke, no problem. I did backtrack on my initial answer though. I thought that you could access the Vue instance in the `next` callback, but that's only in the `beforeEnter` navigation guard, not `beforeEach`. I still think using Vuex is a good solution in your case, so I've tweaked it a little.