# How to save reference to "this" in Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, umd

I'm not sure if I'm doing this properly. Please have a look at this simple Vue component `Test.vue`:

```
<template>
    <div>
        Hi from {{name}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    let self;

    export default {
        created: function () {
            self = this;
        },
        methods: {
            load() {
                ajax().then((obj) => self.name = obj.data);
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                name: 'one',
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

As you can see I'm saving the reference of this into a variable called `self` because the **value of `this` changes in lambda functions**, e.g. `ajax().then((obj) => self.name = obj.data);`

My problem is when this another instance of component is created, it overwrites the value of `self` in previous instance. So for example if I have two `<test id="1"></test>` and  `<test id="2"></test>` then the later component overwrites the `self` variable of the first one (same happens in `v-for` too).

So my question is how can I create the `self` variable which saves to the value of `this` for every instance and doesn't get overwritten?

**Edit:** Yes I know I can do `self = this` inside every function but this is just a bare-bones example with 1 method. In my actual component I have 20+ functions I don't want to do `self = this` in every function. Which is why I can to create a variable that I can just assign once during the `create` call and use it everywhere (like we used to use `that` variable).

Comment: Why not do `let self = this;` just before the `ajax()` call? What you're experiencing is an issue with scoping. By placing the variable declaration within the scope of `load()`, you avoid overwriting the value with additional assignment operations.

Comment: You can simple use this.name. I thought arrow functions are meant for that purpose. It takes the scope of the containing block

Comment: @karthick, indeed `this` should work where self is used in the example.

Comment: The reason why `let self` is getting over-written is that it's created globally. If you wish it to be per-instance, move it to the `data` property of the component.

Comment: It's true that `this` changes in a lambda. But you're not using any lambda, you're using the `arrow function`. And in arrow function, `this` does not change since an arrow function doesn't have its own `this`. Therefore, your entire effort is.. pointless.

Comment: @N.B. a lambda function is just an [anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function) or an expression who's value is a function. Arrow functions can be (and often are) lambda functions. In OP's case, it's a lambda function.

Comment: I'm very tempted to [close this as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) because all the answers are there, but will leave open because OP is attempting to use a closure, which would work, but defining `self` in the wrong place so it fails.

Comment: @B.Fleming please see my edit. I have a lot of functions (this was just a simple example). I don't want to repeat it over and over. Also the value of `this` changes when I use it in the fat-arrow functions, esp when using `.then` call (I often get this.load not defined which i can easily fix using the `self`, i.e. this is pointing to something else)

Comment: Where you likely got into trouble was defining *methods* (or lifecycle handlers, or computed properties) with arrow functions. [You can't do *that* with Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929650/vuejs-why-is-this-undefined) because then `this` will refer to the enclosing scope (usually undefined in ES6). You want to use arrow functions when defining callback functions (as you do for `then` handers) *inside* methods, lifecycle handlers, etc.

Comment: @N.B. You said "you're not using any lambda, you're using the arrow function". That's wrong. OPs arrow function is a lambda.

Comment: @Bert so am I correct in thinking that you're saying that I said that an arrow function used here **was not a lambda**? Because, I wrote that he is not using JUST ANY lambda, his lambda is an ARROW function, and an arrow function hasn't got its own `this`. I see how it might have gotten about the wrong way.

Comment: @N.B. Yes, that is how I interpreted what you wrote. Your clarification absolutely helps!

Comment: @Bert yea, I should probably pay more attention to attributes when relaying what I meant, when I re-read what I wrote I figured I missed the word `just` :) thanks for the pointer though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are attempting to do is mostly *unnecessary*.

It is true that the value of `this` can be confusing at times in JavaScript. It is also true, though, that this is a well known problem, with well known solutions.

And these solutions, at least in problems related to the Vue instance, are:

- [**Arrow functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and
- [**Function#bind()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

But don't trust me just yet, let's go through an example. Take your source code:

```js
    methods: {
        load() {
            ajax().then((obj) => self.name = obj.data);
        }
    },
```

As argument for the `.then()` you must pass a function. The value of `this` inside such function *will depend on **how** you pass it*.

In the first case (first solution from the two solutions above), one should use **arrow functions** (which you did). So, in that point of your code, the `self` is unnecessary because the `this` inside the arrow function still will point to the Vue instance.

```js
    methods: {
        load() {
            console.log(this.name);
            ajax().then((obj) => this.name = obj.data);
        }
    },
```

In the example above, both `this.name` refer to the **same** property. See demo below.

```js
const ajax = () => {
 return fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/18gqg9')
     .then((response) => response.json())
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  name: 'Alice'
  },
  methods: {
    yoo() {
      console.log('outside:', this.name);
      ajax().then((obj) => { this.name = obj.name; console.log('inside arrow, after change:', this.name); });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>
    name: {{ name }}
  </p>
  <button @click="yoo">AJAX!</button>
  
  <p>Click the button above and check the console. The printed name variable is the same.</p>
</div>
```

Now, in the second solution, you would use a **regular (non-arrow) function**. But to make sure the `this` is kept, you would **use `.bind(this)`**, as follows:

```js
    methods: {
        load() {
            console.log(this.name);
            ajax().then(function (obj) { this.name = obj.data }.bind(this));
        }
    },
```

Similar to the previous case, in both places `this.name` refers to the same property. See demo below.

```js
const ajax = () => {
 return fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/18gqg9')
     .then((response) => response.json())
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  name: 'Alice'
  },
  methods: {
    yoo() {
      console.log('outside:', this.name);
      ajax().then(function(obj) { this.name = obj.name; console.log('inside arrow, after change:', this.name); }.bind(this));
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>
    name: {{ name }}
  </p>
  <button @click="yoo">AJAX!</button>
  
  <p>Click the button above and check the console. The printed name variable is the same.</p>
</div>
```

So, as you can see, within the Vue instance, the declaration of such `self` variable is unnecessary.

Comment: You are right, I tried the code and it seems to work. But there have been many instances where I get an error like `this.load` is not defined, but when I save `this` in `self` and use that it works. Let me try to find that code sample. I've seen that `this` sometimes point to something else and it the reason why I had to come up with this whole saving `this` into another variable thing.

Comment: Sure, find it out and show us. You probably are doing something like `ajax().then(this.someMethod);` in this case, you *have* to use `.bind()`, like:`ajax().then(this.someMethod.bind(this));`

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. It was `ajax().then(this.load)`. I now see why it is wrong to do that without bind (even though if I'm not wrong, `ajax().then(self.load)` seems to work). Thanks for the help.

Comment: You don't *have* to use bind in `ajax().then(this.someMethod)`. Methods are already bound to Vue and cannot be re-bound. [Here is an example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/jzmGOZ?editors=1010).

Comment: Indeed they are!

Comment: Anyway, using arrow functions or `.bind()` is the standard way of handling the `this`.

Comment: @Bert, @acdcjunior thanks for explaining it to me and I now understand it correctly. I somehow misunderstood the arrow function changes the `this` operator which is of course incorrect. I don't see the need to use `self` anymore.