# How can I implement arrow function in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

My method in vue looks like this :

```
methods: { 
    setDate: async function () {
        console.log(this.modal)
    }
}
```

I want to change it to an arrow function. I tried like this :

```
methods: { 
    setDate: async () => {
        console.log(this.modal)
    }
}
```

There exist error like this :

```
Cannot read property 'modal' of undefined
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you can directly use function as `setDate () { }`, there is no need to use `:`

Comment: methods: { setDate() { console.log(this.modal) } }

Comment: You should not use arrow function as a method in vue js.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJS: why is "this" undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929650/vuejs-why-is-this-undefined)

Comment: @VibhaChosla @Rich @Antonio Try to read my question well. I use `async`

Comment: you can use `async`  as `async setDate() { }`

Answer (score 1):

use function directly like

```
methods: { 
    async setDate() {
        console.log(this.modal)
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a difference between `async setDate() {` and `setDate: async function () {`?

Comment: The former is [a newer syntax introduced in ECMAScript 2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions). So the only real difference is in terms of browser support

Answer (score 1):

You are facing this error because an arrow function wouldn't bind this to the vue instance for which you are defining the method. The same would happen if you were to define computed properties using an arrow function.

Don’t use arrow functions on an instance property or callback e.g.

```
vm.$watch('a', newVal => this.myMethod())
```

As arrow functions are bound to the parent context, this will not be the Vue instance as you’d expect and `this.myMethod` will be undefined.

You can read about it [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods).

Answer (score 0):

This link https://michaelnthiessen.com/this-is-undefined/ says the following:

"An arrow function uses what is called lexical scoping. We'll get into this more in a bit, but it basically means that the arrow function takes *this* from it's context.

If you try to access *this* from inside of an arrow function that's on a Vue component, you'll get an error because *this* doesn't exist!

So in short, try to avoid using arrow functions on Vue components. It will save you a lot of headaches and confusion."