# Vue.js cannot access this is lifecycle hooks

Tags: vue.js

Sup folks,

I have a lifecycle hook declared inside component like this:

```
export default {
  created: function() {
    console.log(this)
  },
}
```

console prints `vueComponent`, all good.

However if I change it to an arrow function like so:

```
export default {
  created: () => {
    console.log(this)
  },
}
```

now `this` is `undefined`.

Why? Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: There’s a call-out box in the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) with the first sentence: `Don’t use arrow functions... Since an arrow function doesn’t have a this`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJS: why is "this" undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929650/vuejs-why-is-this-undefined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this` keyword becomes unavailable in that scenario because arrow functions have no `this` context, so javascript looks in the outer scopes for that value. That means that if you use arrow functions, `this` will often be either `undefined` or take on an undesirable value.

That is also stated in [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks). Inside your Vue instances, avoid arrow functions.

Answer (score 2):

It is already stated in the docs

from the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks)