# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '$store' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuex, store

I want to build an application with vue3 and vuex. I have got an error when I use $store (*Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '$store' of undefined*). But I did not find anything about that. Could you help me?

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import { store } from "./store";

createApp(App)
  .use(store)
  .use(router)
  .mount("#app");
```

main.js

```
<template>
  {{ posts }}
  <button @click="clickOnButton">Tıkla</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  computed: {
    posts: () => this.$store.state.post
  },
  methods: {
    clickOnButton: () => {
      this.$store.commit("getPost");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

component

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VueJS: why is "this" undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929650/vuejs-why-is-this-undefined)

Answer (score 2):

The problem has nothing to do with your store. You are using an arrow function when you should be using the standard method syntax:

```js
// ...
  methods: {
    clickOnButton() {
      // this will now point to your component.
      this.$store.commit('getPost');
    }
  }
// ...
```

The foremost limitation of arrow functions is that they are totally agnostic of context: `this` is not bound. See the [vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks)

[image: Vue says not to use arrow functions as a property or callback]

and the [arrow functions documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function expression is a compact alternative to a traditional function expression, but is limited and can't be used in all situations.
>
> Differences & Limitations:
>
> - Does not have its own bindings to `this` or `super`, and should not be used as methods.

Comment: [Vuex 4 removes $store typing by default](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/migrating-to-4-0-from-3-x.html#typescript-support). Just adding this here because they'll have this problem next.